# How to prove that $Y=\ln(X)$ approximately Normal when $X$ is a Normal random variable with $\mu\gg\sigma$

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variables

I wanted to prove that PDF of $Y=\ln(X)$ tends to a Normal distribution with $\mathcal{N}(\ln(\mu_{x}),\sigma^{2}_{y})$ when $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_{x},\sigma^{2}_{x})$. It is also important to note that $\mu_{x}\gg\sigma_{x}$. Important is that $Y$ tends to a Normal distribution with mean $\mu_{y}\simeq\ln(\mu_{x})$.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have any thoughts or things you've tried? Regards

Comment: Yeah, I have been trying to expand the exponential series after getting the PDF of Y and then trying to simplify that as a Normal distribution by employing relation $\mu>>\sigma$ but that is not helping. Perhaps, after simplifying the $e^{2y}$ and $e^{y}$ terms in the exponential series and assuming that this is a Gaussian distribution with mean $ln(\mu_{x}$ and then equating with $E[X]$ of the simplified PDF may help. I am trying but no success.

Comment: $Y=\ln(X)$ is a single random variable and cannot tend to anything. You will have to make your question more precise.

Comment: When $Y$ would be another RV, with some distribution which intuitively can be approximated with a Normal Distribution because of the nature of logarithm operation and associated condition of $E[X]$ far greater than $\sigma_{x}$, why can it not be proven mathematically?

Answer (score 1):

Informal version: when $\mu_x\gg \sigma_x$, the logarithm is close to the linear function $t\mapsto \ln \mu_x+t/\mu_x$ on the interval $[\mu_x-5\sigma_x,\mu_x+5\sigma_x]$ where pretty much all of $X$ lives.

More formally: the pdf of $Y$ is $g(y)=e^y f(e^y) $ where $f$ is the pdf of $X$. Since $f(e^y)$ is extremely small outside of $$I= [\ln(\mu_x-5\sigma_x),\ln(\mu_x+5\sigma_x)]$$ we focus on $y$ in this interval.  Using the Taylor approximation centered at $\ln \mu_x $ we obtain 
$$e^{y}= \mu_x + \mu_x(y-\ln \mu_x) +\theta(y)\, (y-\ln \mu_x)^2,\quad y\in I \tag2$$
where $|\theta(y)|\le \frac12 (\mu_x+5\sigma_x)$. Here 
$$|y-\ln \mu_x|\le \ln(1+5\sigma_x/\mu_x)\le 5\sigma_x/\mu_x$$ which is small. 
Thus, 
$$e^y f(e^y) =  \mu_x\, f(\mu_x + \mu_x(y-\ln \mu_x))+O(y-\ln \mu_x) \tag3$$ where $O$ can be explicitly estimated as above. The function $\mu_x f(\mu_x + \mu_x(y-\ln \mu_x))$ describes the normal  curve centered at $\ln\mu_x$ with variance $\sigma_x^2/\mu_x^2$.